I need to change the post type slug in URL to "city" custom field
I have a listing post type that works great. I even have a rewrite rule that takes a URL like "/chesapeake/user-x-llc" and redirects to the "/listings/user-x-llc". However, I want the URL to stay "/chesapeake/user-x-llc" for SEO and usability purposes.
Is this possible? No matter what I try it results in 404 errors.
UPDATE
I have a rewrite rule that takes "[city]/[name]" and redirects to "index.php?post_type=listings&city=[city]&name=[name]" and this works.
However, once the page is loaded the URL displays "listings/[name]" and I want it to remain "[city]/[name]".
I added the post_type_link filter like so:
static public function filter_post_type_link($permalink, $post) {
  if ($post->post_type == 'listings') {
    $locations = get_field('listing_locations', $post->ID);
    $city_slug = '';
    if ($locations && !empty($locations)) {
      $city_slug = sanitize_title($locations[0]['city']);
    }
    error_log('ListingHelper::filter_post_type_link: ' . home_url(user_trailingslashit("$city_slug/{$post->post_name}")));
    $permalink = home_url(user_trailingslashit("$city_slug/{$post->post_name}"));
  }

  return $permalink;
}

This results in a 404 error. It is my understanding that if the URL returned in the post_type_link matches the original link that it will redirect while displaying the original link.
What am I doing wrong? It is very frustrating.


Add the following code in the child theme or in the custom plugin:

     function listings_type_rewrite_slug($args, $post_type) {
        // Check if it's the listings post type
        if ($post_type === 'listings') {
        // Check if it's the main query and if we are on a taxonomy archive page
            $args['rewrite'] = array(
                'slug' => 'chesapeake', // Change 'chesapeake' to your desired slug
            );
        }
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'listings_type_rewrite_slug', 10, 2);


Go into wp-admin
Open Settings->Parmalinks
Click the Save button
Clear the browser cache and check

